# filter object and get all items that have the same value javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, lodash

I have an object like this

```
filters = [
  {gpo1: [{name:"a", selected: false}]
  },
  {gpo2: [{name:"b", selected: true}]
  },
  {gpo3: [{name:"a", selected: false}
           {name:"b", selected: false}
           {name:"c", selected: true}
           {name:"d", selected: false}
           {name:"e", selected: true}]
  },
  {gpo4: [{name:"f", selected: false}
           {name:"h", selected: false}
           {name:"r", selected: true}
           {name:"w", selected: false}
           {name:"x", selected: true}]
  },
]
```

and I need to get this result

```
selectedFilters = [
  {gpo2: [{name:"b", selected: true}]
  },
  {gpo3: [{name:"c", selected: true}
           {name:"e", selected: true}]
  },
  {gpo4: [{name:"r", selected: true}
           {name:"x", selected: true}]
  }
]
```

I've looked for some alternatives with lodash but so far I have had no luck :(
I hope someone can help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild the object with filtered items.

```js
const
    filters = [{ gpo1: [{ name: "a", selected: false }] }, { gpo2: [{ name: "b", selected: true }] }, { gpo3: [{ name: "a", selected: false }, { name: "b", selected: false }, { name: "c", selected: true }, { name: "d", selected: false }, { name: "e", selected: true }] }, { gpo4: [{ name: "f", selected: false }, { name: "h", selected: false }, { name: "r", selected: true }, { name: "w", selected: false }, { name: "x", selected: true }] }],
    result = filters.flatMap(o => {
        const entries = Object.entries(o).flatMap(([k, v]) => {
            v = v.filter(({ selected }) => selected);
            return v.length
                ? [[k, v]]
                : []
        });
        return entries.length
            ? Object.fromEntries(entries)
            : [];
    });
 
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```